# why some permalinks adding characters/ruining links

Tags: permalinks, links, characters

I am using a gallery to link to some sub categories. Some of the links within the category work exactly how they should. However there are a few that are adding strange characters on the end, I've re-done the permalinks but it still does it, you cannot see the extra characters in the link section of my gallery admin. Obviously by adding these characters, it is preventing the link from working and giving me the 404 message. It is vital to my website that my links work.

Can anybody think of a reason why they would not? I have tried disabling plugins and also looked for invisible characters.

"%20%E2%80%8E" variants of this are what is being added.

Really hoping someone can help me to solve this! Thanks.

Comment: Can you give us some examples of what a link should be, and what it's FULL output is. (and where you are putting said links within the gallery).

Comment: I am using a gallery called Pinwheel slider and at it appears at the bottom of wp media library. You can select to put the image into a slider and then input a slide link url. This is where i put the link and it does work on a few.This is what i am putting in as an example http://www.tbdowenholland.com/our-products/unpowered-gs/ ‎directly from the edit page and after clicking the image, this is what appears http://www.tbdowenholland.com/our-products/unpowered-gs/%20%E2%80%8E

Comment: Okay. As I said, give some examples of your input vs. the output. It could be to due with special characters or spaces in your link (%20 is a space, for example)

Comment: I pressed enter by accident-I was putting the output in, its above in my original post, just in case you aren't notified of an edit.

Comment: See my answer. Chances are some hidden breakpoint characters were on the HTML page where you copied those from (or even Word Doc). Go to the first link, and then copy it directly from the address bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are you are copy+pasting the links in, correct? Depending where you are copying from, they could be filled with hidden space characters, like `<wbr>` in the actual HTML (if you copy from a website) which offers a break point. You need to paste these links into TextEdit, or Notepad, or Event the browser address bar to make sure no spaces are being stuck in there by mistake.

Comment: That is correct, I will re-do them and try it in notepad first. Thanks.

Comment: Notepad should work great, but if it doesn't, use a browser. That's the best way to make sure the link works properly!

Comment: I just tried it, I am copying them from the permalink in the page edit and when i copied into notepad there was nothing untoward about the link, no extra characters/spaces etc.

Comment: So hopefully now copying it from Notepad will fix the issue.

Comment: I'm not longer getting the error message, however rather than opening the link, it is going to an attachment page?

Comment: Well, then maybe you have an attachment that is named the same, and WordPress is overriding the link. Best to find the subcategory link you actually want, and copying it from the address bar there.

Comment: No I don't think I do. I tried copying from notepad to a different image and i still got the same strange characters.

Comment: Once I manually typed the permalinks in they worked fine. There must have been something hidden in them that i was too blind to see. Thanks for all your help Eric.

Answer (score 1):

The ugly URL trailing with ***%e2%80%8e*** is result of copy-paste content from Word, Excel or web page content. In this case copied content may include the special character which sometimes hidden ASCII space character. Just follow the below steps,

1. Go to ***cPanel*** > ***phpMyAdmin***
2. Select the WP database
3. Click on ***Search*** tab
4. Enter value ***%e2%80%8e***. Select ***the exact phrase*** with table ***wp_post***. Please note that the table name might be vary; however usually ends with the word ***post***.
5. ***Browse*** the results. Now click on Edit link
6. Navigate toward ***post_name*** and remove the ugly content.
7. Finish

Hope this will help you. Based on the solution from DoubtSolver.

Answer (score 0):

I just got this error. I was able to fix it easier than the replies you get here. Copy pasting in TextEdit was just doing the same thing, my URL still had these ugly characters:

```
https://girlknowstech.com/fr/%EF%BB%Bajouter-trello-google-calendar-ical
```

So what I did was that I edited the permalink of my post. I deleted everything, and re-typed it with the same thing I just deleted. My link now works as it should. I'm guessing there was an invisible character that was getting in the way! :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything in here but nothing worked. At the end I switched browser from Edge to Chrome, retyped and it worked as it should've from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found that deleting the permalink and re-typing manually instead of copying from the post title solved the issue.

Now my concern is this, what if the same funny characters are in the body of the post, invisible to the human eye but detected by search bots, won't it affect the content? Since the sentence was copied from the article's body.